# File transfer from client to server

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, file-transfer

I am trying to send a file from client to server. It sometime worksand sometime don't. when first time trying to send file, it sends corrupt file and the file side formed at server side is double of its size. But file successful transfers for all attempts after first attempt. Can anyone help me with this ?

Client.c

```
     message msg;
        msg.type = SEND_FILE;
        char *username, *filename;

        username = strtok(input+6, " ");
        filename = strtok(NULL, "");

        //Get Picture Size
        printf("Getting Picture Size\n");
        FILE *picture;
        picture = fopen(filename, "r");
        int size;
        fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(picture);
        fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_SET);

        //Send Picture Size
        printf("Getting Picture Size\n");
        sprintf(msg.data, "%d", size);
        strncpy(msg.username, username, 20);

        if(send(connection->socket, &msg, sizeof(message), 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("Send failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Send Picture as Byte Array
        printf("Sending Picture as Byte Array\n");
        char send_buffer[size+1];
        fread(send_buffer, 1, sizeof(send_buffer), picture);
        write(connection->socket, send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer));
        bzero(send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer));
```

server.c

```
  //Read Picture Size
printf("Reading Picture Size\n");
int size = atoi(message_text);

//Read Picture Byte Array
printf("Reading Picture Byte Array\n");
char p_array[size];
printf("Converting Byte Array to Picture %d\n", size);
FILE *image;
image = fopen("c4.png", "w");
int readSize = 0;
while (readSize < size) {
  readSize = readSize + read(clients[sender].socket, p_array, size);
  fwrite(p_array, 1, sizeof(p_array), image);
}

fclose(image);
```

Comment: Post complete functions and structure definitions, or better complete programs that show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters:

You don't want to store the same number of bytes on every `fwrite()`

```
fwrite(p_array, 1, sizeof(p_array), image);
```

but only the number of bytes actually read.

`sizeof(p_array)` returns the size of `p_array`, which is `size` times the size of a `char`. The latter is defined as being `1`.

---

Besides this the call to `read()` *completely* lacks error checking, along with the test whether the other side shut down the connection. This is not leading far.

---

To fix this you could do:

```
#include <errno.h> /* for errno */

...

  size_t size = atoi(message_text);
  printf("Reading Picture Byte Array\n");
  char p_array[size];
  size_t readSize = 0;
  while (readSize < size) {
    ssize_t result = read(clients[sender].socket, p_array, size); /* Mind the ssize_t, it's *not* size_t! */
    if (0 >= result)
    {
      if (0 == result)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "The other end gracefully shut down the connection.\n");

        break;
      }
      else
      {
        if (EINTR == errno)  /* got interrupted, start over */
        {
           continue;
        }

        if (EAGAIN == errno)  /* in case reading from a non-blocking socket: no data available, start over */
        {
           continue;
        }

        /* Something went wrong unrecoverable. */
        perror("read() failed");

        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
       fwrite(p_array, 1, result, image); 
       /* Also add error checking here! */
       readSize += result;
    }
 }
```

Comment: @alk thanks, worked for me. Can you please tell me, how much file size I can transfer using this ?

Comment: @chqrlie: Too often I typed `errno = EAGAIN`... :} and decided to never search such bugs again!

Comment: @MukeshGupta: Until your disk blows up, or you starved waiting for the transfer to finish ... ;-) So ***do not*** forget to add error checking here: `fwrite(p_array, 1, result, image);`

Comment: @alk: yes, who hasn't... but `-Wall -Werror` or equivalent is the better fix to present this silly mistake and many others.

Comment: @chqrlie: I adapted this style long ago, before compilers went that smart ... ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie: Having a look at your profileI feel  you most likely remember those times ... :-)

Comment: @alk: I most certainly do! Those were the happy days, before the tears came falling, with the plusses, sharps and GCs...